# How to use CIELAB to obtain illumination invariance in image processing?

Tags: image-processing, colors, computer-vision, color-space

I found out that taking the Euclidean distance in RGB space to compare two colors in applications like image segmentation is not recommended because of its dependence on illumination and lighting conditions. Furthermore, because of the numerical instability of the HSV *hue* value at low intensity, the CIELAB color space is said to be a better alternative.

My problem is that I don't understand **how** to actually use it: Since CIELAB is device independent, you cannot simply convert to it from some RGB values without knowing anything about the sensor that was used to obtain these RGB values. As far as I know, you have to convert to CIEXYZ in an intermediate step first, but there are several different [matrices](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html) available depending on the exact RGB working space of the source.

Or is it irrelevant which matrix you choose if you only want to use CIELAB to compare two colors (as I said, for example to perform image segmentation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the exact color space that you're converting from, you may use [sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srgb) - it was designed to be a generic space that corresponded to the average monitor of the time. It won't be exact of course, but it's likely to be acceptable. As you observe, perfect accuracy shouldn't be necessary for image segmentation, as the relative distances between colors won't be materially affected.

Comment: Thank you! So I should just take the RGB values (each component ranging from 0 to 255), divide them by 255 (i.e. map them to [0,1]) and then multiply them by [this matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation) to get CIEXYZ values? How important would the linearization step described in the link above be in this case?

Comment: @ph4nt0m, the linearization step is vital, don't skip it. The conversion to CIELAB will apply its own curve and having two curves applied will completely wreck the properties of CIELAB that make it desirable in the first place.

Comment: OK, but isn't the linearization step described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation) specific for sRGB? So if I don't know the exact color space of my source (after all, I just have some RGB values of unknown source in the range [0, 255]), how should I know how to linearize my values?

Comment: @ph4nt0m, that was the point of my answer - if you don't know the proper linearization to use, use sRGB because it's likely to be as close as any other guess you could make.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess applying [this](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=02#text2) and then [this](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=07#text7) is exactly what I should do to convert from RGB to CIELAB. Is it right that the distance between two colors in CIELAB should be calculated by the Eucl. distance over L*, a* and b*? Other sources say that you have to discard the L* component to reach the illumination independence, but others argue that CIELAB itself was designed so that colors of the same "hue" are already close together (with respect to all three coordinates).

Comment: @ph4nt0m, looks about right. The hue is roughly the angle in the a*b* plane, while the saturation is the distance from the a*b* origin. I'd start with the 3D distance, then drop L* only if you run into trouble.